# Assigning same value to 2d struct object array

Tags: c, arrays, object, struct

```
Struct student
{
        char last_name[30];
        char first_name[30];
};
Struct examination_seating
{
        struct student** seating;
};
void student_init_default(struct student *p)
{
        *p->first_name=*"###";
        *p->last_name=*"###";
}
void examination_seating_init(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct examination_seating *t)
{
        for (int i=0; i<rownNum; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<columnNum; j++)
                {
                        student_init_default(&t->seating[i][j]);
//this creates a read access violation
                }
        }
}
```

I am working on a school project and have it written but am having difficulty debugging. My TA and teacher is providing little help. I submitted parts of the code I am having issues with. I need to assign a default value from student_init_default function to the array. If I try to do it with char I get errors as well. I couldn't find any clear references online.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code from `main()` to see how is `t` initialized and passed?

Comment: Here is a link to the file on my onedrive. It said too many characters for me to send on here. I am not allowed to modify the main(). A classmate finally replied to one of my requests for help and suggested that it was my student_init_default function that could be the problem. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak0lyQ6mgOKgkcxbo9fc-5o22u5FAQ?e=nV207C

Answer (score 0):

```
        *p->first_name=*"###";
        *p->last_name=*"###";
```

C strings cannot be assigned this way (this assigns only the first character). We have to use [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm):

```
        strcpy(p->first_name, "###");
        strcpy(p-> last_name, "###");
```

Moreover, since `student_init_default(&t->seating[i][j])` *creates a read access violation*, you haven't correctly initialized `t` or `t->seating[i]`, so it was unwise that you only *submitted parts of the code* you're *having issues with*.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has cut down the errors so far. Also I did have it initialized with ```&t->seating[rowNum][columnNum\;``` but accidentally deleted it. Now I am having issues with the assigning the default values. I tried strcpy and get various errors, my gut is telling me to use the student_init_default function but it too doesn't work.

Comment: `&t->seating[rowNum][columnNum];` initializes neither `t` nor `t->seating[]`.